# grep string including forward slash as part of word

Tags: bash, grep

How to treat `/` as part of word and grep exact match?

```
$ echo "aa/bb/cc dd/ee/ff" | grep -w aa/bb
aa/bb/cc dd/ee/ff
$
```

I want grep to match the whole string without exception to `/`.
In the above example, I don't want it to match `aa/bb/cc` string, but match only if there is any `aa/bb`

Expected outputs:

```
$ echo "aa/bb/cc dd/ee/ff" | grep <options??> aa/bb
$ <empty>
$ echo "aa/bb dd/ee/ff" | grep <options??> aa/bb
aa/bb dd/ee/ff
$ echo "kk/ll aa/bb dd/ee/ff" | grep <options??> aa/bb
kk/ll aa/bb dd/ee/ff
$ echo "kk/ll dd/ee/ff aa/bb" | grep <options??> aa/bb
kk/ll dd/ee/ff aa/bb    
$ echo "kk/ll dd/ee/ff aa/bb/cc" | grep <options??> aa/bb
$ <empty>
$ echo "kk/ll dd/ee/ff a-aa/bb" | grep <options??> aa/bb
$ <empty>
```

Comment: Please provide expected output for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`grep`** approach:

```
echo "aa/bb/cc aa/bb dd/ee/ff" | grep -P '(?:^|\s)aa/bb(?=\s|$)'
aa/bb/cc aa/bb dd/ee/ff
```

---

```
echo "aa/bb/cc aa/bb dd/ee/ff" | grep -P '(?:^|\s)aa/bb(?=\s|$)'
<empty>
```

---

- `-P` - perl regex
- `(?:^|\s)aa/bb(?=\s|$)`:

  - `(?:^|\s)` - non-captured group with alternation group to match either the start of the string `^` or whitespace character `\s`
  - `aa/bb` - match `aa/bb` sequence literally
  - `(?=\s|$)` - lookahead positive assertion containing alternation group to match either whitespace character `\s` or the end of the string `$`

Comment: this matched `echo "aa/bb/cc dd/ee/ff aa/bb" | grep -Ew 'aa/bb(\s|$)'` but this didn't match: `echo "aa/bb/cc aa/bb dd/ee/ff" | grep -Ew 'aa/bb(\s|$)'`

Comment: @rodee, please mention your all requirements in your post and together so that we could try to help you.

Comment: @rodee, what if the input is `echo "aa/bb/cc -aa/bb dd/ee/ff"` ?

Comment: it should NOT match `echo "aa/bb/cc -aa/bb dd/ee/ff"`

Answer (score 1):

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) with `-P` perl regex switch :

```
$ grep -P '(?<=\w)aa/bb(?![/\w])'
```

### Note:

I use [*look around*](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) advanced regex technique. Even if the link is for perl, it's a good ressource (it's not specific just for perl)

Comment: thanks, found RomanP's solution easy to remember, thanks for the answer though, it works.